# How do I find a Specific File Name in Batch and change to that directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am coding a batch file that will get the directory of a specific file(curl_for_64bit.exe). I tried using the find command but it does not work. It basically gets the directory of the file, changes to that directory so that it can be copied.

Comment: `dir curl_for_64bit.exe /s`.

Comment: what does /S mean?

Comment: Type `dir /?` at a command prompt - it means "search subdirectories*. Using *whatevercommand /?* works on almost all Windows command line programs.

Comment: How do I now switch to that directory. I mean as soon as the directory is known, the batch will automatically change to that directory?

Comment: Now you're asking another separate question. Your question here is *How do I find a specific file name*. If that's not what you wanted to ask, then [edit] your question to ask what you really want to know.

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse the directory tree with a `FOR` command checking for the existence of the required file until it's found

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
  if exist %%a\curl_for_64bit.exe (
    pushd %%a
    goto :eof
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script searches the file `curl_for_64bit.exe` in the directory tree rooted at `C:\ROOT\` and changes to the parent directory where the found file is actually located:

```
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "C:\ROOT\curl_for_64bit.exe"') do (
    cd /D "%%~dpF"
)
```

Or this command line to be typed directly into `cmd`:

```
for /F "delims=" %F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "C:\ROOT\curl_for_64bit.exe"') do @cd /D "%~dpF"
```

To learn what the `~dp` modifier of the `for` variable `%%F` means and how it works, open a new command prompt window, type `for /?` and read the help text (see the last section in particular).

Answer (score 0):

you can use command like @Ken White say, then use other code to get the file's directory.

here is my code

```
rem you should go to the specific root directory(like c d e etc.)
cd /d c:\
dir /s /a /b curl_for_64bit.exe >tmp.txt                                                
set /P file_path=<tmp.txt                                                   
del tmp.txt

cd /d %file_path%\..
```

And if you just want to copy those files, why you want to go to the directory of file?