# how to locate and open a file in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can i search for a program in a directory and open it via cmd?
I tried using following command
    `dir /s c:\myprogram.exe`
but this only shows me the directory in which my program is, but doesn't open it.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39365152/2152082)

Comment: Also, you can use the `where` command , i.e _for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (where /R "%programfiles%" winrar.exe) do start "" "%i"_. Double the percent sign if you are running inside a batch file. The quotes surrounding `"%programfiles%"` and `start "" "%i"` are relevant if path or filename contain spaces

Comment: Edit: The only percent sign to change in batch file are all the ocurrences of `%i` to `%%i`

Comment: *If* the path to the parent directory of your program `myprogram.exe` is stored in the `%PATH%` variable, simply run it by writing `myprogram.exe` or `myprogram` into command prompt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for example this sample batch file to open winrar file :

```
@echo off
Set "Folder=%ProgramFiles%"
Set "MyFile=winrar.exe"
CD /D "%Folder%"

for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%MyFile%"') do (
    echo "%%~dpF" & pause
    Start "" %MyFile%
)
```

Or we can use this command **`Where /?`** as ***elzooilogico*** provided on the comment :

```
@echo off
Where /R "%programfiles%" winrar.exe
pause
For /F "delims=" %%i in ('Where /R "%programfiles%" winrar.exe') do start "" "%%i"
pause & exit
```