# How to delete some words in a specific line without removing the line completely?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am getting the path of a file named curl_for_32bit. Now it replies with this:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 901C-31D8

 Directory of C:\Users\onlYUs\Documents\jezreel\32BIT

08/24/2016  05:24 PM         1,768,448 curl_for_32bit.exe
           1 File(s)      1,768,448 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
           1 File(s)      1,768,448 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  126,746,275,840 bytes free
```

Now what I want is to get only the line starting with Directory of.. and then, remove the word directory of.. so that what is left would be a path.

Edit:
To output only the line with directory.. is done. Now my question is how do I remove the words "Directory of" so that a path will remain?

```
 Directory of C:\Users\onlYUs\Documents\jezreel\32BIT
```

Comment: You question is about searching... Did you even try to search for an answer before asking this?

Comment: CloseVote: Questions must demonstrate a minimal attempt to solve the problem. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work

Comment: sounds like a X-Y-Problem. You can get the folder with `for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "curl_for_32bit.exe"') do set "folder=%%~dpF"`

Comment: Changed the question. Is there a way to remove only the words Directory of.. without removing the line completely?

Comment: Your question initially stated that you were looking for a file named curl_for_64bit, and despite finding a file under a directory named 64BIT  your output was showing a 32bit executable. You have still not provided the code you tried, despite having edited your question. We would like to know what you've tried and what you are wanting to do with the resultant and required output. _Also I'd suggest that you may not need to search for files if you weren't saving executables within a directory intended for documents._

Comment: Oh sorry. I just misplaced the file but for now it is fixed. I'll change it

Comment: if you insist doing it that way: [see here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: How many questions have you planned to post concerning the same issue? 1. [How do I find a Specific File Name in Batch and change to that directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39360642) (which seems to cover the core issue you are trying to solve, and what I provided an answer for) 2. [How to Find a Specific text in a Specific line of text in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39363512) 3. [How to delete some words in a specific line without removing the line completely?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39366367)

Comment: @aschipfl just vote to close he didn't hear nobody here ! he just open new thread with new title with the same issue and you provide him a solution and he didn't reply and open and reopn new thread, so i vote to close this !

Comment: If you really think that way, then I will agree with your proposal Mr. Hackoo. Anyways, thank you for the solutions, guys! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the other linked questions on the same issue, I'm assuming you want the path to the directory as a variable:

```
@Echo Off
For /R \ %%I In ("curl_for_32bit.exe") Do Set var=%%~dpI
```

or if you only wanted to move to that directory:

```
@Echo Off
For /R \ %%I In (curl_for_32bit.exe) Do CD /D %%~dpI
```